# Change WkWebView constraint with keyboard problem

Tags: swift, keyboard, autolayout, wkwebview

I made two top/bottom views. And I add WkWebView at top.

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification)
{
    menuHeightConstraint.constant = 0
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification)
{
    menuHeightConstraint.constant = 50
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

When keyboard show, I made to hide bottom view.

I just load twitter share link in webview

```
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20world")!)
webView!.load(request)
```

When twitter web login and keyboard show, touch 'Done' key for hide keyboard.

Keyboard will show again.

This will not happen unless the constraints are changed.

Sample Source
https://github.com/NoviceGom/WebViewSample

Could someone point out the wrong part?

Answer (score 1):

```
 @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification)
  {
    view.endEditing(true) // this line will work for you
    menuHeightConstraint.constant = 50
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 }
```

add the above line and it will works for you the above line is used for dismiss the keyboard.

Thanks